# react native ActivityIndicator is not rotating/animating

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, activity-indicator

React Native version: 0.55

i have the following code in a screen in a react native app:

```
<ActivityIndicator animating={true}/>
```

And for some unknown reason, the ActivityIndicator is NOT rotating. It shows as static and start animating ONLY AFTER any state change occurs on the screen.

any idea why?

Comment: I'm experiencing a failure to animate on only on Android in my Share Extension.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that it can depend on the device that is being used.  I spent an hour on the same problem on a LGE G6 before I pulled up the same project on a Samsung Galaxy S8.  Not only was it animating on the Samsung Phone but the indicator itself looks very different.  It might be that the LGE phone doesn't have such a component as a spinning activityIndicator.  The static image I get on this phone looks more like a refresh button anyway.

In summary, I think that not all android devices support animating ActivityIndicators, so there is not an issue with your code, but rather with the interface between React Native and the native code.

Answer (score -3):

It's just simple:

```
<ActivityIndicator size="large" animating/>}
```

Link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html#docsNav